# Appcelerator TableView - Unknown click regions. Need help to understand

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm using Appcelerator to build the mobile application and I have add a TableView() on Window(). Inside a TableView(), it's styled as a GroupView and it has a headerView() and a footerView(). I have two TextField()s and I want it to blur() when click on the non-TextField() region. However, when I mapped it out, I realized, I can't find the Click() Events occured in the Orange and Pink region and hence, I can't blur the textfields when both the region is clicked!

Any help is very much appreciated. The pink region is due to the fact that I set a height to the footerView().

[image: TableView Problem]

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view with height Ti.UI.FULL and add a click event listener that does the blur to it. Then add all your elements to your new view and add your view to the window.

Comment: it doesn't really work. on the same note, i realized when i click the tableviewrow, both window.click and tableviewrow.click got fired. anyways that only tableviewrow.click get fired and not window.click?